# Approach to save ajax requests in jQuery pending user action

Tags: jquery, ajax

The script below is part of a specialized text editor and works well. It sends an ajax request after 'blur'.

Because it contacts the database so frequently we want to compile these requests and then send them all at once via ajax when the user hits a 'SAVE' button.

I was wondering if there is a standardized approach for something like this in jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#resume_holder").ready(function () {

  $('#resume_holder').contents().find('[contenteditable]').on("focus", function(e) {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.data('before', $this.html());

  }).on("blur", function(e) {

     var $this = $(this);
     var before = $this.data('before');
     var txt = $(e.target).closest("section").html();
     var id = $(e.target).closest("section").attr('id');

                $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : '<?php echo site_url('resume/edit_resume_ajax'); ?>',
                        dataType: "html",
                        context : $(this),
                        data: {
                            edit_id: id,                                
                            edit_value: txt,
                            edit_before: before
                        },
                        success : function(msg){
                        console.log(msg);
                        },
                        error: function(msg){
                        console.log(msg);
                        }
                    }); 
                }); 
            });

 });    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the options would be:

1. HTML5 Local Storage.
   If the request queue/data needs to be retained even if the page is refreshed/changed then I would go with HTML5 Local Storage. See [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) or have a search.
2. If it's a list/array of data just store it in a Javascript variable until the save button is clicked, if the data doesn't need to persist after a page request.
3. Instead of doing the ajax call `onblur()`, detect the `onblur()` and record the period of time between the previous `onblur()`, if it's over X minutes then do the save ajax request.

Comment: Thanks -- good insights. Probably going to go with the 2nd route -- but never would have thought of #3, which would be a very cool autosave.